# Bazel dependency on genrule from cc_library doesn't build

Tags: cross-compiling, bazel

I'm stumped :(

I am porting some Makefiles for a very complex embedded system to Bazel, and I'm running into some problems with some weird dependencies I have.

Some background, so you know why I'm doing this weird stuff: I'm building for a TI C6000 series processor using a cross-compiler toolchain I've developed. TI provides a configurable BIOS for the processor which you configure using a java tool they provide.  This creates a bunch of files, including linker command files and compiler command files.  They have a non-standard extension, and Bazel is picky about the extensions, so I am copying the command files files with the extension `.lds` in my `genrule`.

I can build this directly, but when I try to build a `cc_library` that depends on the BIOS being built (and hence the command files being available), then it does not build the BIOS first.

Here is the relevant `genrule`. I'm including the code verbatim because I'm wondering if I have some subtle syntax error that is causing the issue. The shell part has grown in complexity as I have tried to debug.  I will probably make it into a separate shell script once things are working.

```
genrule(                                                                                                                           
    name = "libs",                                                                                                                 
    srcs = [                                                                                                                       
        ":deps",                                                                                                                   
        "ti_bios_without_edma3.cfg",                                                                                               
    ],                                                                                                                             
    outs = [                                                                                                                       
        "compiler.opt",                                                                                                            
        "compiler.opt.lds",                                                                                                        
        "linker.cmd",                                                                                                              
        "linker.cmd.lds",                                                                                                          
        "package/package.defs.h",                                                                                                  
        "package/cfg/ti_bios_without_edma3_pe66.h",                                                                                
        "package/cfg/ti_bios_without_edma3_pe66.oe66",                                                                             
        "package/cfg/ti_bios_without_edma3_pe66.src/utils/utils.ae66",                                                             
        "package/cfg/ti_bios_without_edma3_pe66.src/sysbios/sysbios.ae66",                                                         
        "package/cfg/ti_bios_without_edma3_pe66.src/ipc/ipc.ae66",                                                                 
    ],                                                                                                                             
    cmd = """                                                                                                                      
rm -rf "$(@D)" \                                                                                                                   
  && $(location //phy/platform/ti_bios_common:xdc_parser.sh) \                                                                     
     $(location ti_bios_without_edma3.cfg) \                                                                                       
     "/workspace/output/bazel_output_base/execroot/cap/$(location linker.cmd)" \                                                   
     "$(@D)" > /dev/null \                                                                                                         
  && cp $(location linker.cmd) $(location linker.cmd).lds \                                                                        
  && cp $(location compiler.opt) $(location compiler.opt).lds                                                                      
""",                                                                                                                               
    tools = ["//phy/platform/ti_bios_common:xdc_parser.sh"],                                                                       
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],                                                                                          
)
```

Here is the rule that depends on it

```
# TI optimized math library                                                                                                        
cc_library(                                                                                                                        
    name = "math_ti",                                                                                                              
    srcs = [                                                                                                                       
        "src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c",                                                                                    
        "src/ti_c66x/add_cmplx_vec.c",                                                                                             
        "src/ti_c66x/add_real_vec.c",                                                                                              
        "src/ti_c66x/calc_abs_val_vec.c",                                                                                          
        "src/ti_c66x/calc_positive_real_vec_log.c",                                                                                
        "src/ti_c66x/calc_positive_real_vec_sqrt.c",                                                                               
        "src/ti_c66x/calc_vec_cos.c",                                                                                              
        "src/ti_c66x/calc_real_vec_exp.c",                                                                                         
        "src/ti_c66x/calc_real_vec_alog.c",                                                                                        
        "src/ti_c66x/div_real_vec.c",                                                                                              
        "src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat.c",                                                                                        
        "src/ti_c66x/multiply_real_mat.c",                                                                                         
        "src/ti_c66x/multiply_real_vec.c",                                                                             
        "src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_vec.c",                                                                                        
        "src/ti_c66x/tw_alog.c",                                                                                                   
        "src/ti_c66x/tw_log.c",                                                                                                    
    ],                                                                                                                             
    hdrs = [                                                                                                                       
        "math_generic.h",                                                                                                          
    ],                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                   
    copts = [                                                                                                                      
        "--cmd_file=$(location //phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:compiler.opt.lds)"                                             
    ],                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                   
    linkopts = [                                                                                                                   
        "-@$(location //phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:linker.cmd.lds)"                                                        
    ],
    visibility = [                                                                                                                 
        "//visibility:private",                                                                                                    
    ],                                                                                                                             
    deps = [                                                                                                                       
        ":math_generic",                                                                                                           
        ":math_generic_novla",                                                                                                     
        "//phy/include:common",                                                                                                    
        "//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:compiler.opt.lds",                                                                   
        "//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:linker.cmd.lds",                                                                     
    ],                                                                                                                             
    data = [                                                                                                                       
        "//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:libs",                                                                               
    ]                                                                                                                              
)
```

For the life of me, I cannot get it to build the BIOS before building the `math` library. If I manually build the BIOS first and then build the `math` library, then my build succeeds, but in a clean build, the `math` library build fails because the BIOS has not been built yet.

I'm using Bazel 1.1.0 in an Ubuntu 16.04 Docker on x86

Sorry for writing a novel.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

The query `$ bazel query "deps(//phy/lib/math:math_ti)"` gives me

```
...
//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:linker.cmd.lds
//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:compiler.opt.lds
//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:libs
//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:ti_bios_without_edma3.cfg
//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:deps
...
```

so it is indeed recognizing `//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:libs` as a dependency, but it doesn't build it before building my library:

```
SUBCOMMAND: # //phy/lib/math:math_ti [action 'Compiling phy/lib/math/src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c', configuration: 04904b24bebbf24a56366c3e37012771]
...
ERROR: /twbuild/rj/2work/tarana3/cpu/applications/src/phy/lib/math/BUILD:192:1: C++ compilation of rule '//phy/lib/math:math_ti' failed (Exit 1)
>> ERROR: Cannot open command file 'bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3/compiler.opt.lds': No such file or directory
...
```

None of the subcommands show it trying to build `//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:libs`

After these commands, I can run a find and don't see any of the generated files:

```
$ find -L  . -name compiler.opt.lds
$
```

If I build `//phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:libs` directly, then I do see the generated files:

```
$ find -L  . -name compiler.opt.lds
./bazel-src/bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3/compiler.opt.lds
./bazel-bin/phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3/compiler.opt.lds
./bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-null for //phy/lib/math:math_ti
  Mnemonic: Middleman
  Target: //phy/lib/math:math_ti
  Configuration: ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10
  ActionKey: 5c25f976e1ff1473093bcd3508178109
  Inputs: [bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Sinclude_Ccommon-null, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Ugeneric-null, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Ugeneric_Unovla-null, phy/lib/math/math_generic.h]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Uti-null]

action 'Compiling phy/lib/math/src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c'
  Mnemonic: CppCompile
  Target: //phy/lib/math:math_ti
  Configuration: ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10
  ActionKey: 92f17fb0219b9758ba79e3c77721e5c7
  Inputs: [bazel-out/host/internal/_middlemen/tools_Sti_Ucompiler_Cempty, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Uti-null, external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/grep-includes.sh, phy/lib/math/src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.d, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.o]
  Command Line: (exec tools/ti_compiler/wrapper_scripts/cl6x \
    -ppa \
    -k \
    -pden \
    -pdv \
    -pdew \
    -c \
    --c99 \
    '--diag_error=225' \
    -O3 \
    phy/lib/math/src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c \
    --output_file \
    bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.o \
    '-ppd=bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.d' \
    -I. \
    -Ibazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin \
    -Iexternal/ti_toolchain/include \
    -Ithird_party/ti/dsplib_c66x/packages \
    -Ithird_party/ti/mathlib_c66x/packages \
    -DPLATFORM_C10 \
    -DROLE_BN \
    '-DPLATFORM=B10' \
    '-DROLE=BN' \
    --verbose \
    '--cmd_file=bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3/compiler.opt.lds')
bn_c10/bin/phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3/compiler.opt.lds
```

Edit:

I didn't realize that `bazel aquery` was a thing.  I see the line

```
action 'Executing genrule //phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3:libs'
```

at the *bottom* of the `aquery` output, which I presume means Bazel wants to execute it *after* all of my compiles, instead of before.

Here is the top of the results of `aquery`:

```
null for //phy/lib/math:math_ti
  Mnemonic: Middleman
  Target: //phy/lib/math:math_ti
  Configuration: ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10
  ActionKey: 5c25f976e1ff1473093bcd3508178109
  Inputs: [bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Sinclude_Ccommon-null, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Ugeneric-null, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Ugeneric_Unovla-null, phy/lib/math/math_generic.h]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Uti-null]

action 'Compiling phy/lib/math/src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c'
  Mnemonic: CppCompile
  Target: //phy/lib/math:math_ti
  Configuration: ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10
  ActionKey: 92f17fb0219b9758ba79e3c77721e5c7
  Inputs: [bazel-out/host/internal/_middlemen/tools_Sti_Ucompiler_Cempty, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/internal/_middlemen/_S_Sphy_Slib_Smath_Cmath_Uti-null, external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/grep-includes.sh, phy/lib/math/src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c]
  Outputs: [bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.d, bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.o]
  Command Line: (exec tools/ti_compiler/wrapper_scripts/cl6x \
    -ppa \
    -k \
    -pden \
    -pdv \
    -pdew \
    -c \
    --c99 \
    '--diag_error=225' \
    -O3 \
    phy/lib/math/src/ti_c66x/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.c \
    --output_file \
    bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.o \
    '-ppd=bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/lib/math/_objs/math_ti/multiply_cmplx_mat_vec.d' \
    -I. \
    -Ibazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin \
    -Iexternal/ti_toolchain/include \
    -Ithird_party/ti/dsplib_c66x/packages \
    -Ithird_party/ti/mathlib_c66x/packages \
    -DPLATFORM_C10 \
    -DROLE_BN \
    '-DPLATFORM=B10' \
    '-DROLE=BN' \
    --verbose \
    '--cmd_file=bazel-out/ti_c6000-opt-bn_c10/bin/phy/platform/ti_bios_without_edma3/compiler.opt.lds')
```

So indeed it is not seeing `compiler.opt.lds` or `linker.cmd.lds` as inputs.

Comment: What error are you getting? "file not found" for one or both of the `.lds` files? There are a couple things you can do to help diagnose this: after a clean, build the library with `--subcommands` to confirm that the `libs` genrule is getting run. Then do a `bazel aquery` on `math_ti`, and confirm that the `.lds` files are actually being added to the inputs of the relevant actions (not just the command lines). I'm guessing that while having the `.lds` files in the deps will cause them to get built, the `$(location)` aren't causing them to get added to the inputs, so they aren't in the sandbox

Comment: I put the answers to your questions into the question to allow for formatting.  I don't think the issues is that they are just not found, because it never tries to build the library, but if I manually build it first, then the build succeeds.

Comment: so `query` will return target-level dependencies, which look fine, that just tells you that the `.lds` files are indeed listed in deps. `bazel aquery //phy/lib/math:math_ti` will tell you if the inputs you need are actually getting added to the action. Moving the `.lds` files to `data` instead of `deps` may work. `aquery` will tell you what's going on

Comment: "if I manually build it first, then the build succeeds" -- do you mean if you build `libs` first, then build `math_ti`, it works? Are you running without sandboxing?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using sandboxing or not.  Reading up on it, I think the answer is probably yes. But I'm unsure because we have been using Bazel since v0.11, and we did a complicated migration about 6 months ago to v1.1.0. How can I tell?  Regarding your first question: yes, if I build `libs` first and then build `math_ti`, the build works.

I will see waht happens if I put the `.lds` files in the data section instead

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that it is using the wrong compiler: `Configuration: k8-opt` and `(exec /usr/bin/gcc`... this is probably realted, let me take a look

Comment: Oh, no scratch that, I just wasn't providing the right arguments to `aquery`.   When I provide the same arguments I use for `build`, it uses the right compiler, but same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216672/discussion-between-user961826-and-ahumesky).

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing down the answer to my issue for posterity:

The reason why it was not recognizing the `libs` target as a dependency during the compile is that Bazel seems (understandably) to interpret files with `.lds` extensions as being used during the link phase.  Accordingly, it would not build the `libs` target until it needed it for linking (e.g. after compiling).

In order to work around this I added an unnecessary header dependency to my `math_ti` target that then triggered the build during the compile phase instead of only during the link phase.

Thanks a million to @ahumesky !!! He helped me sort though what was going on and I learned a ton about Bazel in the process!